# Useless sugesstion in Intellisense VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, csproj

I'm using Vscode

> Version: 1.55.2
> Commit: 3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d
> Date: 2021-04-13T09:36:32.643Z (3 wks ago)
> Electron: 11.3.0
> Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
> Node.js: 12.18.3
> V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
> OS: Darwin x64 20.3.0
> Blockquote

with **Unity 2019.4.15f1**

sometimes VSCode IntelliSense gives useless suggestions.

For example, In below image [image]

For enum "ForceMode" the allowed values are

```
     Force = 0,
    Impulse = 1,
    VelocityChange = 2,
    Acceleration = 5
```

but IntelliSense is showing suggestions like
`csproj_1.0`
`csproj_2.0`
etc.

How to fix these useless suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. Go to settings.
2. search for "quick suggestions"
3. open "settings.json"
4. add: "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
5. Done, test and see if it works

This may remove some other options from Intellisense aswell.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is the settings.json I have and you try it yourself. Maybe extensions can change the settings
{"editor.quickSuggestions": {"other": true,"comments": false,"strings": false},"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": true,"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on","editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true,"editor.tabCompletion": "off","editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,"editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed","editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,"editor.parameterHints.enabled": true,"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
}